# OutOfMemoryError , Google Direction API (ANDROID)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I was using my google maps app successfully and it works perfectly fine from all respect. but when i tried to get direction from two too far distance places it crashed and gave a `OutOfMemoryError` to me.

- The places for which i was getting direction is-

  ***Source      - magadan russia***
  ***Destination - cape point south africa***
- **My Logcat**

  ```
  Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 0B until OOM" (recursive case)
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art: "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x744132c0 self=0xb8a7efc0
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:   | sysTid=4871 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6fb4ec8
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:   | state=R schedstat=( 13237478608 1327768343 8667 ) utm=1243 stm=80 core=2 HZ=100
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:   | stack=0xbe1b7000-0xbe1b9000 stackSize=8MB
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:636)
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:     at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:663)
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.MessageLogger.println(SourceFile:83)
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
  04-06 16:42:41.423 4871-4871/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi E/art:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
  ```
- I tried the url in the web to check if it is working or not , but it gave result and worked fine. but have a lots and lots of data.
- The app i have designed was working fine but i have never checked with such long distances (25684 km by google maps app).
- Anyone who is thinking how i was parsing the json data into my app . i have taken my directionparsing from [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)tutorial. i provided the parsing class here because i think this is where the problem is.

**My Research**

I have followed [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4766) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372519/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-with-google-maps-android-api-v2) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533347/mapfragment-google-maps-api-v2-out-of-memory-error-memory-leak) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232638/google-maps-api-v2-out-of-memory-error) SO links but not found much info to solve my problem.

Any suggestion please .

Comment: Are you testing this via emulator or device?

Comment: Also, regarding your code. Is it the same as from the link you provided? Or did you change anything? If so, can you provide your code snippets? :)